Want to Add Display Name while creating new Client Secret in Azure Portal
I want to add Display Name, while creating a new client secret through powershell. is it possible?
I tried too many approad but I am nto able to add name While creating, as this can be done through only Mg-Graph.
I tried using these commands Get-AzureADApplication, Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential.

You can make use of below Microsoft Graph PowerShell command to create new client secret with display name:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

$params = @{
    passwordCredential = @{
        displayName = "Secret name"
    }
}

$applicationId = "appObjID"

Add-MgApplicationPassword -ApplicationId $applicationId -BodyParameter $params

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, secret created successfully with display name as below:

To create the client secret with display name using Azure AD PowerShell module, make use of below command:
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId "appObjID" -CustomKeyIdentifier "Secret Name"

Response:

Portal:

